# My PHP login system still Logging in even if the password or username is incorrect

Tags: php, authentication

Still loggin in even if the username and password is incorrect and also logins even if the value is null

```
<?php 

    $hostname = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "login";
    $conn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if (!$conn) {
        die ("unable to connect");
    }

    if ($_POST) {
        $uname = $_POST ["username"];
        $pass = $_POST ["password"];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$uname' AND password = '$pass' LIMIT 1 ";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
            include("graph.php");
        } else {
            echo "Incorrect"; 
        }
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: if ($_POST)  that mean if data type is post go a head you need more restrictions like empty() , trim(), ....

Comment: Your code looks fine. So.. you should provide more info, like MySQL data and `$_POST` dump.

Comment: Never store plaintext passwords in the database. Use only secure hashes.

Comment: Perhaps you should concentrate on how to restrict access for users who haven't logged in?

Comment: A lot of things wrong here... one of them being (obviously) you are allowing duplicate usernames. That's going to cause you nightmares in the future, SQL injection vulnerability, and more

Answer (score 0):

First of all and **very important** it that **you are open to SQL Injection attack**, so you should use prepared statements, here is how should use your code, but instead of `echo "Incorrect";` you should render different answer for each case:

```
<?php

    $hostname = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "login";
    $conn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if (!$conn) {
        die ("unable to connect");
    }

    if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) { // Check if you have posted data via POST
        $uname = $_POST["username"];
        $pass = $_POST["password"];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ? LIMIT 1 ";

        if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)) { // Check for MySQL errors
            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $uname, $pass);
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                $stmt->close();
                include("graph.php");
            } else { // There is a problem with your SELECT // bind params
                echo "Incorrect";
            }
        } else { // You should handle mysql errors here
            echo "Incorrect";
        }
    } else { // You don't have POST data
        echo "Incorrect";
    }
 ?>
```

[Prepared statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

Like @Kuya notice you have and many other problems, there is a lot of tutorials in Google about implementation of login system.

Answer (score -1):

You must check the post request with `isset()` in php like this :

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST["username"] && isset($_POST["password"]))) {
     //..... Your code here
}else {
    echo "Incorrect password or username";
}
?>
```

Comment: Just because the username and password are posted doesn't mean either one is correct. All your sample code does is ask if they were posted or not.